# live screencasting solution that supports Power PC Macs

Tags: powerpc

I have a Power PC and I have been wanting to do a live screencast of a this thing I do, but there doesn't seem to be a single widget out there that would help me out.

It is not just a matter of grabbing the screen, I have Snapz Pro X and it will work, but I want to share it with a bunch of people in real-time. There is no love for the Power PC architecture.

Any ideas?

:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Copernicus?

http://danicsoft.com/software/copernicus/

Or this (More promising, as it is live):

http://b-l-a-c-k-o-p.com/GrabberRaster.html

Comment: Hey, that GrabberRaster seems like a good start! Any ideas about general video conferencing dealios that support PPC? I was having a hard time finding that as well, but I wasn't exclusively looking for it (what with looking for screencasting primarily). Hmmm... :/

Comment: You should probably create another question for that.

Comment: Also, if my answer answered your question, I would appreciate it if you accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

What about VNC? There is a good server for mac that I used to use named [Vine Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/).
Or you could just use the built in one:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Go to Sharing
3. Tick the "Screen Sharing" box
4. Open "Computer Preferences" and make sure the "Allow VNC users to control the screen with a password" box is unticked

And then, on the viewing machine:

1. Open Safari
2. Go to "vnc://*hostname*/" where *hostname* is the ip address/hostname of the server machine